# Are the space captains names meaningful?

Tags: comics, league-of-extraordinary-gentlemen

In the [Black Dossier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_League_of_Extraordinary_Gentlemen:_Black_Dossier) we see a reference to Britain's space industry restarting, referencing Morgan, Dare and Logan.  Is Dare meant to be Dan Dare?  I figure that's a reasonable assumption, given the nature of LXG.  Who are the other two, if that's the case?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wikipedia actually has this answer under [Dan Dare](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dan_Dare). The characters are Jet Morgan from [Journey into Space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journey_Into_Space), a 50s BBC radio serial, and [Jet-Ace Logan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jet-Ace_Logan) from a 50s British comic strip.

Comment: Small mercies. At least they didn't include the hero of the other 1950s radio serial, Orbiter X . He was called "Captain Brittan", and just in case anyone didn't get it, his two children were named - wait for it - Charles and Anne. A decade later, no doubt, they would have given him four kids, but as yet Andrew and Edward were but gleams in Prince Philip's eye.